# Error invalid opcode trying to access Solidity array of structs in Hardhat

Tags: javascript, solidity, hardhat

I have the following struct and array in my Solidity code:

```js
    struct Character {
        int256 strength;
        uint256 dexterity;
        uint256 constitution;
       ....
    }

    Character[] public characters;
```

I have the following line in my Hardhat test attempting to access a member of that array:

```js
const character = await contract.characters(0)
```

I then get the following error:

```sh
 Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
      at Contract.characters
```

What is the correct way to access a member of this array of structs?

Comment: Did you add any items to the `characters` array or was it empty when the error occured?

Comment: @PetrHejda there wasn't, you figured it out. Feel free to answer the question, and I'll mark it correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the question comment, the `characters` array was empty when the `characters(0)` function was called.

Solidity autogenerates getter functions for `public` arrays, allowing to access an item of the array using its index.

When you try to access an index that is out of bounds, the EVM throws an exception.